# Eclipse rcp JFace data binding - run custom method on property change

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I've got problem as follows. In Eclipse RCP application I use JFace data bindings in order to modify model and to have view updated. Everything works great if I use model to update property of the components, that are available in WidgetProperties class.

So it is easy to bind value of the model to property of the component. But is there a way to bind value of the model in order to run some method in UI class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `addChangeListener` method of `IObservableValue` to listen for changes to values in the model or target.

Comment: Do not forget to clean up your ChangeListener or ValueChangeListener when the UI element is disposed! You could also create your own Property. This allows you to delegate cleanup to the Databinding framework.